# Get a list of available migration destination plugins

Tags: 8, migrations, console

how can I get all available migration destination plugins? 
A way to ask with drupal console?

like listed on [Migrate destination plugin examples](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-destination-plugin-examples)

Answer (score 8):

- With **Drupal Console**:

  ```
  $ drupal debug:plugin migrate.destination
  ```

  Or short:

  ```
  $ drupal dpl migrate.destination
  ```

  gives:

  ```
  ------------------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    Plugin ID                                  Plugin class                                                                           
   ------------------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    component_entity_display                   Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\destination\PerComponentEntityDisplay                    
    component_entity_form_display              Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\destination\PerComponentEntityFormDisplay                
    config                                     Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\destination\Config                                       
    d7_theme_settings                          Drupal\system\Plugin\migrate\destination\d7\ThemeSettings                              
    entity:action                              Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\destination\EntityConfigBase                             
    entity:base_field_override                 Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\destination\EntityBaseFieldOverride                      
    entity:block                               Drupal\block\Plugin\migrate\destination\EntityBlock                                    
    entity:block_content                       Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\destination\EntityContentBase                            
    entity:block_content_type                  Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\destination\EntityConfigBase                                                        
    entity:comment                             Drupal\comment\Plugin\migrate\destination\EntityComment                                
    ...
  ```
- With **drush**:

  ```
  $ drush php
  >>> array_keys(\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.migrate.destination')->getDefinitions());
  ```

  gives:

  ```
  => [
   "entity:block",
   "entity:comment",
   "entity:comment_type",
   "d7_field_group",
   "field_group_entity_form_display",
   "field_group_entity_view_display",
   "entity:file",
   ...
  ]
  ```